# Convert Between Latin1-encoded Data.ByteString and Data.Text

Tags: haskell, character-encoding, latin1

Since the latin-1 (aka ISO-8859-1) character set is embedded in the Unicode character set as its lowest 256 code-points, I'd expect the conversion to be trivial, but I didn't see any latin-1 encoding conversion functions in [`Data.Text.Encoding`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/0.11.1.5/doc/html/Data-Text-Encoding.html) which contains only conversion functions for the common UTF encodings.

What's the recommended and/or efficient way to convert between `Data.ByteString` values encoded in latin-1 representation and `Data.Text` values?

Comment: By the way, the assumption that "since the latin-1 character set is embedded in the Unicode character set as its lowest 256 code-points, I'd expect the conversion to be trivial" is unwarranted. There is no reason to expect that the bytestreams resulting from encoding a single codepoint stream in two different encodings should have a trivial relationship to each other.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Yes, I'm aware that in the general case I shouldn't expect this (for instance if `Data.Text` used utf8 as its internal Unicode representation), but the current version of the `Data.Text` library uses UTF16 representation, for which the conversion from latin1 is in fact a trivial conversion consisting in inserting zero octets after or before (depending on whether UTF16LE or UTF16BE is required) each latin1 octet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answer is right at the top of the page you linked:

> To gain access to a much larger family of encodings, use the `text-icu` package: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu

A quick GHCi example:

```
λ> import Data.Text.ICU.Convert
λ> conv <- open "ISO-8859-1" Nothing
λ> Data.Text.IO.putStrLn $ toUnicode conv $ Data.ByteString.pack [198, 216, 197]
ÆØÅ
λ> Data.ByteString.unpack $ fromUnicode conv $ Data.Text.pack "ÆØÅ"
[198,216,197]
```

However, as you pointed out, in the specific case of latin-1, the code points coincide with Unicode, so you can use `pack`/`unpack` from `Data.ByteString.Char8` to perform the trivial mapping from latin-1 from/to `String`, which you can then convert to `Text` using the corresponding `pack`/`unpack` from `Data.Text`.

Comment: not being satisfied with the current options to convert from `ByteString` to `Text` I finally coded up a direct conversion which performs near-optimal and doesn't expose the `IO` monad in its API, see https://github.com/bos/text/pull/18